# Php Curl always return True

Tags: php, rest, curl

Php curl always return TRUE. Though data send in request is wrong and at server side its showing error HTTP 400 -Bad request. here, is my sample code. It should have returned FALSE.

```
 $curl = curl_init($url);

 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"PUT");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$update_para);
 $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: You have not specfied your url here. May be something wrong in url.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when exactly `curl_exec` will return `false` but when the request is sent and response is returned it's certainly not a failure, so it returns `true` - as in "I've managed to send the request and got a response". What is the result of the request on the server-side and contents of the response is completely different thing.

Use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true` to capture the response data, and [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to get other informations, for example `http_code`.

When result of `curl_exec` is `false` use [curl_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) and/or [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to examine what went wrong when trying to send a request.